# Any way to get source code in actual php format from iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I am working with iframe in my php project ,and use iframe to load another php project also from `htdocs(local storage)`.

and i use this javascript  to get source code of single page of project from iframe window

```
var code=document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

and i get the code but all the php statements are in simplified format that is, for an example

`<?php echo "hi">` is changed to hi

and my question is that there is any way to get in actual php format like  this

`<?php echo "hi">` into code variable???

Comment: Well, it's natural that you get the *result* of PHP's execution, not PHP itself. That's how the web works. You can't get the source code of another project, that would be a huge security issue. If you own both projects, you could include some PHP code inside the frame as a code block, but be very careful about what you're exposing to the public.

Comment: your javascript runs in the browser on the client after the server has processed the php and served the request, so no, you can't get server side code with client side javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the php-sourcecode you will have to write a script for that.

Example (reader.php):

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('example.php'); // or $_GET['file'] insetad of 'example.php'
```

The iframe would have to call `reader.php?file=example.php` then.

### Be warned

This is highly insecure. You will have to take care of thw following things:

- Sanitizing user-input
- Prevent directory traversal
- Limit access to only the files you want to be readable
- Be very very sure there are no sensitive information in your php-files.